# i get the this error -->> module 'sagemaker' has no attribute 'describe_training_job'

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using AWS, but I get the following error in this code:

```
 -->> module 'sagemaker' has no attribute 'describe_training_job'
```

This is the code:

```
training_info = sagemaker.describe_training_job(TrainingJobName=job_name)
status = training_info['TrainingJobStatus']
print("Training job ended with status: " + status)

module 'sagemaker' has no attribute 'describe_training_job'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message could also occur if the method does not exist due to running an older version of boto3 than the method you are trying to use. For example, I was running SageMaker Studio's public preview and received the following message.

```
 -->> module 'sagemaker' has no attribute 'create_auto_ml_job'
```

The output of the following did not list `create_auto_ml_job` as an available option.

```
sagemaker = boto3.client('sagemaker')
dir(sagemaker)
```

I found that boto3 was running an older version. Updating boto3 resolved my problem.

```
pip show boto3
pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the high-level `sagemaker` Python SDK has no attribute nor method called `describe_training_job`. 
This is actually a [`boto3` method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.describe_training_job). `boto3` is a lower-level python SDK for all AWS services, that has a SageMaker client. The snippet below illustrates what you want to achieve:

```
import boto3
boto3_sm = boto3.client('sagemaker')

training_info = boto3_sm.describe_training_job(TrainingJobName=job_name)
```

Note that model metrics collected over the logs and sent to Cloudwatch (those typically are performance metrics in the built-in algos, and could be any metrics when you write custom code since you extract them with regexp) are not available with the `describe_training_job` call. That being said, you can get them via the (beta) Search feature:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

response = client.search(
    Resource='TrainingJob',
    SearchExpression={
        'Filters': [
            {
                'Name': 'TrainingJobName',
                'Operator': 'Equals',
                'Value': '<you training job name here>'}]})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.       I checked Status, but I want the correct rate for machine learning(accuracy). What's the command?

Comment: Model performance metrics are not available via this API, but you can collect them via the (beta) search feature - I edited my answer above to write it!